# How to ignore "Cannot find name 'M' " error in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, materialize

I'm integrating a pure javascript library(materialize.js) with my angular typescript app. While activating the sidenav, I need to use the code.

`M.Sidenav.init(document.querySelector('.sidenav'), [])`

This works, and the sidenav is initiated, however, since I didn't define any `M` anywhere in the typescript file, the angular compiler raises an error

`ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(34,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'M'.`

Is there any way I can make typescript ignore this error, or in any way, **fix** it?

Comment: what is M suppose to be? if M is materialize.js, you will need to import it using require()/import

Comment: use 'declare const M'; Also make sure library script file is included and imported.

Comment: Thanks! I using 'declare const M' solved the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can follow these steps

```
npm install --save materialize-css 

npm install --save @types/materialize-css

declare const M;

import { SideNav } from "materialize-css";
```

Comment: You could also set the type of const M: `declare const M: any;`